# can I access a static Arraylist of Vector of another thread? in this example?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, static-members

having problems accessing a static vector from another thread and class in this thread.
one class is the GUI class called LotteryPlay, it has a static Vector called packArray, and the other class called MultiThreader and part of it is shown below, it runs in different thread.  any ideas on what is wrong?

the only thing I could think of is that I am trying to access a static vector from another thread.  is this possible?

```
   @Override
public void run() {
    try {       
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);   
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

       System.out.println("streams are setup from new thread\n");

            line = "";


            while((line = in.readLine())!= null){

             this.messageFromClient(line);

            if(!(counter > 1)){
                textSplitter(line);
                socketPack = new SocketPack(socket, timeStamp, address);
                LotteryPlay.packArray.add(socketPack);   <<<----NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
                System.out.println("SIZE OF PACKARRAY " + LotteryPlay.packArray.size());
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("pakc array "+ LotteryPlay.packArray);
            }

            System.out.println("from client: " + line.trim() + "\n");

            }  // end while loop
```

Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at.com.lotterygame.MultiThreader.run(MultiThreader.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Well presumably `LotteryPlay.packArray` is null. Where are you initializing it? (Not that using a static variable is usually a good idea, mind you...)

Comment: it is initialized in in the other class, LotteryPlay.java,  I have to use a static, because I am storing all the socket objects for client server connections in a static Vector/ArryaList so I can access that list from both classes.

Comment: No, you don't *have* to use a static variable. You just need to redesign things more carefully to make the appropriate data available everywhere it's needed. However, I suspect the problem really is that you're not executing the initialization code. Unfortunately as you haven't shown that, it's hard to pin down the problem any more.

Comment: @codeMan: If it's a static final variable then it's safe to access the variable. How you use the object is then a different matter, of course. Even if it's not final, it's still "somewhat safe" - it's just that unless there's other synchronization, the value written in one thread may not be visible in another thread.

Comment: JON, YOU WERE CORRECT,   I did not initialize the Vector in the LotteryPlay class, after I initialized it in the constructor it works now, no errors.   please put your comment in the form of an answer and i will check it.

Comment: @codeMan: A static final variable is still a static member. Your comment is not helpful without more details, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're getting a `NullPointerException` suggests that `LotteryPlay.packArray` is null. You need to make sure it's initialized before you use it.

If you *really* want to keep it as a static variable, I'd strongly advise you to make it `final`, e.g.

```
public static final Vector<SocketPack> packArray = new Vector<SocketPack>();
```

However, I'd also advise you to redesign your application to avoid requiring static variables. Think about what needs what data, and pass it appropriately. Static variables make code harder to reason about and test.

Additionally, note that although each operation in `Vector` is individually synchronized, that doesn't make it generally thread-safe. For example, you can't safely iterate over a `Vector` without extra synchronization, as otherwise one thread could modify it while you're iterating. You should probably consider the collections in `java.util.concurrent`.